# GameplayKit Longest Path

Tags: swift, xcode, path, longest-path

I want to build GKGraph and find longest path between two points. I see that  GKGraph has a method to find shortest path but for longest I didn't find anything. Can you suggest how can I find the longest path between two points using GameplayKit?